# Idiomatic lazy sorting by multiple criteria

Tags: ruby, performance, sorting, lazy-evaluation, memoization

In Ruby, the most common way to sort by multiple criteria is to use `sort_by` with the sorting function returning an array of the values corresponding to each sorting criterion, in order of decreasing importance, e.g.:

```
Dir["*"].sort_by { |f| [test(?s, f) || 0, test(?M, f), f] }
```

will sort the directory entries by size, then by mtime, then finally by the filename.  This is efficient to the extent that it uses a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to only calculate the size and mtime of each file once, not once per comparison.  However it is not truly lazy, since it calculates the mtime for every single file, but if (say) every file in the directory had a different size, it should not be necessary to calculate *any* mtimes.

This is not a big problem in this case, since looking up the mtime immediately after looking up the size should be efficient due to caching at the kernel level (e.g. IIRC on Linux they both come from a `stat(2)` syscall), and I wouldn't be surprised if Ruby has its own optimizations too.  But imagine if the second criterion was not the mtime, but (say) the number of occurrences of a string within the file, and the files in question are huge.  In this case you'd *really* want lazy evaluation, to avoid reading the whole of these huge files if sorting by size is sufficient.

At the time of writing, the Wikibooks entry for [Algorithm Implementation/Sorting/Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Schwartzian_transform#Full_Schwartzian_Transform) suggests this solution:

```
sorted_files =
  Dir["*"].                         # Get all files
    # compute tuples of name, size, modtime
    collect{|f| [f, test(?s, f), test(?M, f)]}.
    sort {|a, b|                    # sort
      a[1] <=> b[1] or              #   -- by increasing size
      b[2] <=> a[2] or              #   -- by age descending
      a[0] <=> b[0]                 #   -- by name
    }.collect{|a| a[0]}             # extract original name
```

This kind of approach is copied from Perl, where

```
sort {
       $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] # sort first numerically by size (smallest first)
    or $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] # then numerically descending by modtime age (oldest first)
    or $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] # then stringwise by original name
  }
```

works beautifully because Perl has a quirk where `0 or $foo` evaluates to `$foo`.  But in Ruby, it's broken because `0 or foo` evaluates to `0`.  So in effect, the Wikibooks implementation totally ignores mtimes and filenames, and only sorts by size.  I've dusted off my Wikibooks account so that I can fix this, but I'm wondering: what is the cleanest way of combining the results of multiple `<=>` spaceship operator comparisons in Ruby?

I'll give a concrete-ish example to clarify the question.  Let's assume we have two types of evaluation which may be required as criteria during the sort.  The first is relatively cheap:

```
def size(a)
    # get the size of file `a`, and if we're feeling keen,
    # memoize the results
    ...
end
```

The second is expensive:

```
def matches(a)
    # count the number of occurrences of a string
    # in file `a`, which could be a large file, and
    # memoize the results
    ...
end
```

And we want to sort first by size ascending, then descending by number of matches.  We can't use a Schwartzian transform, because that would non-lazily call `matches()` on every item.

We could define a helper like

```
def nil_if_equal(result)
  result == 0 ? nil : result
end
```

and then do:

```
sort {|a, b|
  nil_if_equal(size(a) <=> size(b)) or
  matches(b) <=> matches(a)
}
```

If there are `n` criteria to sort by then you'd need `n-1` invocations of `nil_if_equal` here, since only the last sorting criteria doesn't require it.

So is there a more idiomatic way than this which can avoid the need for `nil_if_equal`?

Comment: Lol... it originally said *"This is not easily represented as Python or Ruby code"* and then someone apparently was like *"Oh really?!"* and [replaced that by the broken code](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Schwartzian_transform&diff=39762426&oldid=39750486), so I guess *"Yes, really!"*. Or was zero actually false back in 2006?

Comment: Haha, nice find :-) Even funnier, the original edit was by Randal Schwartz himself, with the comment "add full-blown ST example (from the horses mouth, so be careful if you edit this, because I ''do'' know what I'm talking about"! No, 0 was never treated as `false` or `nil` in Ruby.

Comment: Hmm, you talk about "truly lazy" and "really want lazy evaluation" and then show that "solution". But that doesn't do lazy evaluation. It does evaluate everything before sorting. It's only lazy in the *comparisons*.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Nope, for example the final solution does not evaluate `b[2] <=> a[2]` unless `a[1]` and `b[1]` are equal. Maybe you are thinking that the hard work was already done by this point in the assignment to `b[2]` and `a[2]`, but a) that's outside the scope of the sort, so not relevant to this discussion, and b) the `<=>` comparison of them could be expensive; in fact even the `[2]` lookup could be too. Nevertheless I can change the example so that this is clearer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ohh I think I see the confusion; you were probably assuming that the final example was just the middle fragment of the sort, sandwiched in between the two `collect`s of a Schwartzian transform. In that case, yes the evaluation wouldn't be lazy, but this was meant as the whole sort, not just the middle with the Schwartzian transform omitted.

Comment: I've updated the example to clarify this now.

Comment: Yes, it looked like you were including the `collect`s. It's better now that your final `sort` code doesn't use those arrays anymore and you have those memoizing helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how idiomatic it is, but here's a way to use `sort_by` again. Instead of
for example

```
['bab', 'foo', 'so', 'bar'].sort_by { |s| [s.size, count_a(s), count_b(s)] }
```

do this to make `count_a(s)` and `count_b(s)` lazy and memoized:

```
['bab', 'foo', 'so', 'bar'].sort_by { |s| [s.size, lazy{count_a(s)}, lazy{count_b(s)}] }
```

My `lazy` makes the block act like a lazy and memoizing version of the value it yields.

Demo output, showing we only count what's necessary (i.e., don't count in `'so'` since it has a unique size and don't count `'b'` in `'foo'` since its `'a'`-count is unique among the size-3 strings):

```
Counting 'a' in 'bab'.
Counting 'a' in 'foo'.
Counting 'a' in 'bar'.
Counting 'b' in 'bab'.
Counting 'b' in 'bar'.
["so", "foo", "bar", "bab"]
```

Demo code:

```
def lazy(&block)
  def block.value
    (@value ||= [self.yield])[0]
  end
  def block.<=>(other)
    value <=> other.value
  end
  block
end

def count_a(s)
  puts "Counting 'a' in '#{s}'."
  s.count('a')
end

def count_b(s)
  puts "Counting 'b' in '#{s}'."
  s.count('b')
end

p ['bab', 'foo', 'so', 'bar'].sort_by { |s| [s.size, lazy{count_a(s)}, lazy{count_b(s)}] }
```

A different way to make `value` memoizing: If it ever gets called, it immediately *replaces itself* with a method just returning the stored value:

```
  def block.value
    def self.value; @value end
    @value = self.yield
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I was wondering about this kind of approach but didn't try it. I'll probably accept this answer, but will wait a little while in case anyone can think of something a little cleaner. I'm also still curious to hear confirmation that there's no easy way to chain `<=>` expressions in Ruby like there is in Perl. BTW, why do you wrap `self.yield` in `[]`?

Comment: @AdamSpiers Yeah, it does feel dirty, I was just trying to make it work and make it simple/short. I wrap the value in an array because the value could be false (i.e., `false` or `nil`) so that `||=` would recompute it. But an array is always true so it prevents that.

Comment: ... just added another way to memoize. Not sure it's better or worse, but at least I find it interesting :-)